Weyl's theorem on complete reducibility, help understanding proof
I'm reading Humphreys' book "Introduction to Lie algebras and representation theory.
I'm having problem following the proof of Weyl's theorem on complete reducibility (theorem 6.3).
In the first paragraph Humphreys assume that the L-module has an L-submodule of codimension 1 and wants to show that we can only regard the case where W is irreducible.

I don't understand how the results of the first paragraph shows that we can consider only the case of $W$ is irreducible. I understand that as long as the codimension 1 L-submodule is not irreducible, we can "factor out" a submodule and get a direct sum of smaller dimensions. But then we should show that this means that the original W is completely reducible and I'm not sure how to do so.
